# Which username password i need to use to login in symfony 2 Admin backend

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-plugins

I have installeed Sonata Admin Bundle and i can access url by `/admin/login`.

now i don't know which username and passowrd to use there.

When i try registered user/pass in `/app/login` it works there but when i enter in admin backend `/admin/login` then it says bad crendtials

Answer (score 3):

You can register a new user through command line:

```
php app/console fos:user:create
```

Than you have to assign the role that you have configured in security.yml. As default it should be ROLE_ADMIN.

```
php app/console fos:user:promote youUsername ROLE_ADMIN
```

Once you have completed these steps, you should be able to login in admin dashboard. If not, try to logout/login again.

Comment: I am stuck with problem that i got two user tables `fos_user` created by my user.php and `fos_user_user` created by sonata user bundle. the user i create in backend r not authenticated as they go in diff table

Comment: Probably, you have to extend FOSUserBundle when you added SonataUserBundle to AppKernel.php. Here is the correct definition: `new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle')`